# Android Studio not opening due to 'internal error'

Tags: android, android-studio

`Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to read /Users/arnavgupta/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2023.1/updatedBrokenPlugins.db
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:236)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.tryReadBrokenPluginsFile(PluginManagerCore.java:262)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.readBrokenPluginFile(PluginManagerCore.java:215)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getBrokenPluginVersions(PluginManagerCore.java:205)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.DescriptorListLoadingContext.(DescriptorListLoadingContext.kt:25)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$resultDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:381)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: getEventDispatchThread() must not be null
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$startApplication$appDeferred$1$rwLockHolderDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:231)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.tryReadBrokenPluginsFile(PluginManagerCore.java:235)
... 10 more

---

Your JRE: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 x86_64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
/private/var/folders/93/__vp7b216sqgtpmwxs3p4fgr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B8DE6D47-07C5-4C80-844D-288981421511/d/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home`

When I opened Android Studio for the very first time after downloading it, it would not open and instead would come up with this error. I do not know what it means and when I tried redownloading the app, the same error came up, what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from other question delete this file and try again

> updatedBrokenPlugins.db

its found under

> C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3

NOTE: its a hidden file make you sure to check show hidden files. in the view tab.

[image]

[image]
for reference check this answer.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-313198

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, I tried deleting the file but it says there is no such file or directory.

Comment: check the updated answer please

Comment: Sorry I might be dumb but I do not know how to locate the image you just showed me on my laptop. I have a macbook fyi.

Comment: open file explorer and click on the view tab that is located on top left corner

Comment: Sorry I was just about to say that I found it and resolved the issue, thank you, your answer helped point me in the right direction :).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did deleting the file work?

Comment: from what I read on the reference link "it's the problem of unconfigured logger: DefaultLogger is used. It looks like we don't wait until it's configured."